# Is there a way to set the direction of the sun light on an object (without rotations)?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

Basically, I'm wondering if I can set the sun lamp's light direction towards a position, such as an object, with a simple command, rather than doing rotations with <kbd>R</kbd> which is hard to control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to do this is with a [*Track To* constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html):

1. Select the sun lamp
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the object you wish to point the lamp at
3. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and choose *Track To Constraint*.

The sun lamp will now always "look" at that object, so you can move it around with <kbd>G</kbd> for easy adjustment.

You can adjust the constraint (or remove it) in the Constraints tab of the Properties area when the sun lamp is active:

[image]

Comment: Although, this works very well for objects, you won't be able to set the direction to a position in 3D space i.e the location of the 3d cursor pointing to that position. Is there a way to do that? Otherwise I'm happy to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @ManWithAComputor I'm not aware of anything exactly like that, however should be possible to create a custom operator which does this (using python). As for something native, you can do some stuff with making the lamp the active camera (`Ctrl Numpad 0`) and using `Ctrl Alt Numpad 0` (align camera to view), which when combined with view manipulation shortcuts (e.g. `Numpad .`) can *sort of* do this. Not exactly "fast" though. In fact, tracking the sun to an empty and snapping said empty to the cursor location (`Shift S`) is likely faster.

Comment: @ManWithAComputer, You could use an Empty (an invisible object) and track to that.